# What's the right ownership for /usr/local for current macOS and Homebrew versions?

Tags: homebrew, permission

Someone told me that

> Homebrew no longer requires /usr/local/ to have an ownership such that it can be written by `brew` commands ...

I recall long time ago I have to manually change the ownership for files and directories in `/usr/local/`.

Now how do I change them back and what is the default or best ownership setting for files and directories in `/usr/local/` for the newest macOS and Homebrew versions?

Answer (score 1):

The correct ownership is `root:wheel` with permissions of 755.